# Grouping the numbers with comma in android

Tags: java, android

Eg:- double ab=1234567.00;

The expected output should be,
ab=12,34,567;

But the following format gives the default three digit grouping.

```
DecimalFormat df_separator = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.00");
```

Also tried with,

```
DecimalFormat df_separator = new DecimalFormat("###,##,##0.00");
```

still in vain.......

Answer (score 2):

Here you are sir,

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
String formattedNr = numberFormat.format(12345678L);
```

This will give you: `12,345,678.00`

Edit:

```
public String formatDouble(double number)
{
    String result = "";
    String numberStr = String.valueOf(number);  
    char[] charArray = numberStr.toCharArray();
    Character[] charObjectArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(charArray);
    for (int i=charObjectArray.length()-1; i>=0 i++)
    {
        if (charObjectArray[i] == ".")
        {
            result = "." + result;
            continue;
        }
        result = charObjectArray[i] + result;
        if (i % 2 == 0) result = "," + result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is pseudo code as I don't have a JVM atm but it should (almost) do the job.

Edit: **Finally**

Add the following jar to your project: http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/NumberFormat.html

```
Format format = com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
System.out.println(format.format(new BigDecimal("100000000")));
```

Comment: can't achieve without jar??

Comment: If you don't want to include the JAR, use JD-gui to get the method and implement your own one ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
double ab=1234567.00;
String str = new DecimalFormat("#,##,##,###.00").format(ab);
Log.d("TAG", str);
```

try this.